# Python , problema con bucle for

Tags: python, bucle-for

> Hola buenas, tengo un problema en Python, cuando la opcion es igual a
>   2, quiero que me muestre una lista con los empleados que he ingresado
>   anteriormente, lo que pasa es que en vez de escribirmelos una vez, lo
>   hace infinitamente. No sé como hacer para que solo sea una, necesito
>   ayuda :)

```
print ("Menú:")
print("   1.-Alta Empleados")
print("   2.-Listado")
print("   3.-Fichero")
print("   4.-Estadísticas")
print("   5.-Salir")

opcion = 0
empleados = []
f = {}

opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))
while opcion < 4:
    if opcion == 1:        
        nombre = input("Nombre: ")
        apellido1 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        apellido2 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        salario = input("Salario: ")  
        fecha = input("Fecha de nacimiento: ")
        cp = input("Código postal: ")
        f=(nombre,apellido1,apellido2,salario,fecha,cp)
        empleados.append(f)
        print(empleados)
        opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar ahora?"))

    elif opcion == 2:

        for empleado in empleados:
            print(empleado)

else:
    print("Se ha acabado")


[('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813'), ('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')]
¿Que acción quieres realizar ahora?2
('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813')
('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')
('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813')
('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')
('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813')
('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')
('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813')
('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')
('Jorge', 'Ramirez', 'Keke', '2000', '10/10/2019', '29813')
('Sara', 'Sanchez', 'June', '2000', '19/10(12', '2913')
```

Comment: Se cicla por que el valor de `opcion` nunca se reinicia , despues del for vuleve a ponder `opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))`

Answer (score 2):

Te falta volver a solicitar al usuario qué quiere después de mostrar los datos:

```
print ("Menú:")
print("   1.-Alta Empleados")
print("   2.-Listado")
print("   3.-Fichero")
print("   4.-Estadísticas")
print("   5.-Salir")

opcion = 0
empleados = []
f = {}

opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))
while opcion < 4:
    if opcion == 1:        
        nombre = input("Nombre: ")
        apellido1 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        apellido2 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        salario = input("Salario: ")  
        fecha = input("Fecha de nacimiento: ")
        cp = input("Código postal: ")
        f=(nombre,apellido1,apellido2,salario,fecha,cp)
        empleados.append(f)
        print(empleados)
        opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar ahora?"))

    elif opcion == 2:
        for empleado in empleados:
            print(empleado)
        opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))
else:
   print("Se ha acabado")
```

o bien, pides la opción fuera del if ...

```
print ("Menú:")
print("   1.-Alta Empleados")
print("   2.-Listado")
print("   3.-Fichero")
print("   4.-Estadísticas")
print("   5.-Salir")

opcion = 0
empleados = []
f = {}

opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))
while opcion < 4:
    if opcion == 1:        
        nombre = input("Nombre: ")
        apellido1 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        apellido2 = input("Primer apellido: ")
        salario = input("Salario: ")  
        fecha = input("Fecha de nacimiento: ")
        cp = input("Código postal: ")
        f=(nombre,apellido1,apellido2,salario,fecha,cp)
        empleados.append(f)
        print(empleados)
    elif opcion == 2:
        for empleado in empleados:
            print(empleado)
    opcion = int(input("¿Que acción quieres realizar?"))
else:
   print("Se ha acabado")
```